# Standard Input/Output ignoring content

Tags: java, html, io, network-programming

I have writtten a code that accepts user input from the console and stores it into a file on my desktop. This works fine when i run the program on my IDE. I would like to run it over a network (xinetd to be exact) so that when i enter "localhost" on my browser, xinetd redirects the Std Input/output to be displayed on my browser. In this case, the user input entered via console will be displayed on the browser: Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\out.txt")));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
        System.out.println("Enter some text");
        for(String in=br.readLine(); !in.equals(""); in=br.readLine()){
            bw.write(in);
            output.add(in);
        }
        System.out.println(output);

    }
    System.out.println("Zugriff aufgezeichnet");

}
```

When i run it over the network: 1) I'm prompted to enter text but the browser does not wait for my input and just gives out the general http get-request message like this:

```
Enter some text
[GET / HTTP/1.1, 
Host: localhost, 
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0, 
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5,
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate,
Connection:Keep-alive
Cache-Control:max-age=0]
Zugriff aufgezeichnet
```

This shows that the html request is being saved into my ArrayList and nothing else (since i did not get a chance to input anything into the console). I would like to get a chance to enter something into my console before anything is outputted. After "Enter some text", i would like for it to await for user input.

Comment: Its unclear from your question what you want to achive ?

Comment: instead of checking for empty !in.equals("") check for carriage return "\r\n" as regex

Comment: What console? Do you think you can emulate a console with a browser? Where do you think you are supposed to enter your input?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, fair enough. I just realised this too -_-. Can you think of a workaround?

Comment: Can't offer a workaround because I'm not actually sure what you are trying to achieve.